# PHP pack with type H doesn't work

Tags: php, pack

I'm trying to convert a hex link to text on another page.

Here's part of the code that should do it:

`URL = url.php?post=48656c6c6f20736972733f`

```
$file = $_GET['post'];
$file = pack("H*",bin2hex($file));
echo "<h2 class='center'>The file " . $file . " does not exist</h2>";
```

or

```
$title = pack("H*",bin2hex($_GET['post']));
$title = ucfirst($title);
echo $title;
```

The output on these are "48656c6c6f20736972733f"

Comment: Why `bin2hex`? Just remove it.

Comment: So it's like pack("H*"($file)); ?

Comment: Kind of. `pack("H*", $file);`.

Comment: Thanks man that worked! Just answer something, so that I can end this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
pack("H*", $file);
```

Worked great